# Does fill structures from pointers make the acess to that struct undefined after free?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say that we have the following case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    struct test *ptest = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    struct test jtest;
    ptest->a = 3;
    ptest->b = 2;

    jtest = *ptest;
    free(ptest);

    printf("a: %d\nb: %d\n", jtest.a, jtest.b);
    return 0;
}
```

As I've freed the pointer to `ptest`, and consequently the memory area that it refers to, my access to `jtest` is compromised after the free of `ptest`? Or when a make a dereference to assign the values of `jtest` it's made a copy of the values present on the address of `ptest`?

Comment: I recommend you take some pen and paper and draw three boxes. Label one `ptest` and another `anonymous test structure object`. Then draw a pointer from `ptest` to `anonymous test structure object`. That's basically how pointers work. Then take the third box and label it `jtest structure object`. The assignment you do is copying from `anonymous test structure object` to `jtest structure object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, if you're not using pointers, a copy is always made. So, when `ptest` is freed, `jtest` still has its own copy of the memory.

Comment: Could you please give a pointer to where this behaviour is defined? I've made some research and didn't find anything

Comment: @Matheus If `ptest` is a pointer to a `test` structure, then `*ptest` is an actual `test` structure. And you can copy between structures just by using assignment.